# Balance the load equally among multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading

For my school assignment, I need to balance the load equally among multiple threads in C. For example, I need to compute the summation of integers in the interval `[0, 50]` balancing the load equally among 5 threads (the interval and number of threads are just an example, they could be much bigger values). My first idea was to divide the interval into 5 smaller ones, e.g. `[0,10], [10,20]...[40,50]` and assign each one of these chunks to one particular thread. But then I got some doubts about whether computing the sum of integers in the interval [0,10] is the same load as computing the sum of integers in the interval `[40,50]`, because obviously numbers in the latter interval are bigger, so it made me wondering if calculating 10x10 is the same load for CPU as 100000x100000? Should I be concerned about this? Your kind feedback would be much appreciated.

P.S. English is not my first language, so please forgive me for my grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be very concerned. That's a poor design. Not only might some intervals require more work than others but some threads might make forward progress faster than others for a variety of implementation-specific reasons.

So *don't* assign large chunks of work to threads. Have threads take *small* chunks of work and then take another chunk when they're finished. That approach makes much more sense.

Essentially, you have a queue of work that needs to be done. Threads take small work units off the queue and repeat until the queue is empty.